# As400- How to send mail from sqlrpgle program by taking data from a database file and send it as excel

Tags: ibm-midrange

I want to send mail from sqlrpgle program where data is taken from database file. And send it as excel document. Also want to specify the column headings in that excel. How can I do that? Could anyone please help.?

Comment: Modern POWER servers running IBM i can send email, setting that up is outside the scope of SO.  And there are various tools for generating Excel documents from the i.  Recommending on is again, out of scope for SO.

Comment: you can do this by having the SQLRPGLE program use `HTTPPOSTCLOB` to send a request to a web service on a PHP server running on the IBM i.  The PHP web service then  uses PHP Mailer to send the email message with the excel attachment.  The SQLRPGLE program passes json formulated data to the PHP web service. Use json_object sql function to do that.

Comment: Or just use a Java call to JavaMail